# The import org issue in spring java project

Tags: java, spring

I am a novice to java and novice to spring as well...
I am creating my first java spring application using following link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm

But I am getting this error on MainApp.jav- 
***The import org cannot be resolved.***

Please see link given for steps i followed. 
Please note I am not creating maven project.

Please help...
[image]

Comment: Why don't you add some scree shot of the error you are getting. It will be clear to figure out the issue

Comment: Seems you haven't handle with external dependencies. You'd better paste it with screentshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependencies in your pom file , for imports. When you add a dependency , a jar file gets added in your maven or any other project, then you can import the org you want.

Comment: Sorry,initially i though its Maven project but its not. 
its just a java project.

Comment: Try adding spring-context jar in your project, then your imports may work.

Comment: If you have spring-context in your libraries, then you need to check whether your spring context jar contains ApplicationContext.class , then only you can import that class in your project. To my knowledge, it should contain, you can try using spring context 4.3.14 release and build your project again.

Comment: And try making pom.xml file to add all the dependencies that you want to add in your project, it may also help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved ! 
What i did - removed the import references and resolved it automatically by its class names.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the dependencies in the project in order to get the import statements.
add this to the pom.xml in to resolve the issue.

```
<properties>
<org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please format your code (even if it is "only" xml) properly.

Comment: Sorry,initially i though its Maven project but its not. 
its just a java project.